# How to set a panel as a parent of an instantiated prefab in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to instantiate a `Prefab` and then make a `Panel` the parent of it. but it gives me this error:

```
Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a Prefab Asset is disabled to prevent data corruption (GameObject: 'TargetIcon').
UnityEngine.Transform:SetParent(Transform)
```

How can I get ride of this error?

Here are the details:

I have a panel in a canvas which serves as a minimap. I have a prefab to be instantiated and the panel should be made as parent to this prefab. this code is attached to my panel:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MapObject {
    public Image icon {get; set;}
    public GameObject owner { get; set; }

}

public class MiniMapController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform playerPos;
    public Camera mapCamera;

    public static List<MapObject> mapObjects = new List<MapObject>();

    public static void RegisterMapObject(GameObject o, Image i)
    {
        Image image = Instantiate(i);
        mapObjects.Add(new MapObject() { owner = o, icon = i });

    }
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        DrawMapIcons();
    }



    void DrawMapIcons()
    {
        foreach(MapObject mo in mapObjects)
        {
            Vector3 screenPos = mapCamera.WorldToViewportPoint(mo.owner.transform.position);
            mo.icon.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
            screenPos.z = 0;
            mo.icon.transform.position = screenPos;
        }
    }
}
```

and then this code is used to make a mapobject:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MakeMapObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public Image image;
    void Start()
    {
        MiniMapController.RegisterMapObject(this.gameObject, image);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

I don't know why is this giving me the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is likely here:

```cs
public static void RegisterMapObject(GameObject o, Image i)
{
    Image image = Instantiate(i);
    mapObjects.Add(new MapObject() { owner = o, icon = i });
}
```

You are instantiating the image, but then you pass on the prefab to your `MapObject`.

Try doing:

```cs
mapObjects.Add(new MapObject() { owner = o, icon = image });
```